# Type 'Pagination<UserEntity>' is missing the following properties from type 'UserEntity':

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I am implementing pagination using this https://github.com/nestjsx/nestjs-typeorm-paginate.

and i am receiving the error mentioned in the title in this line:

`return this.usersService.findAll({ page, limit });`

Any idea what seem to be the issue ? thanks.

Here is my controller

```
@Roles('User')
  async findAll(@Query('page') page = 0, @Query('limit') limit = 10): Promise<UserEntity> {
    limit = limit > 100 ? 100 : limit;
    return this.usersService.findAll({ page, limit });
  }
```

Here is my service

```
async findAll(options: IPaginationOptions): Promise<Pagination<UserEntity>> {
  return await paginate<UserEntity>(this.usersRepository, options);
}
```

Comment: Hi Adam, it seems the error you mentioned in the title is incomplete. What are the actual properties missing from UserEntity? Please provide the whole error.

Comment: Type 'Pagination<UserEntity>' is missing the following properties from type 'UserEntity': id, firstName, lastName, password, and 11 more.ts(2740)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so it's basically a type mismatch. In the controller you are returning a Primise of UserEntity, however in the service which you are invoking you are returning a Promise of Pagination of UserEntity. The 2 things do not match, so the TS code will not compile, since the compiler things, most of the time for good reason, that the resulting js will lead to runtime errors.